# I think I understand this. But is there a way to make this simpler?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++ and I came across this code:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main() 
{  
  const long feet_per_yard = 3;  
  const long inches_per_foot = 12;  
  double yards = 0.0;                       // Length as decimal yards  
  long yds = 0;                             // Whole yards  
  long ft = 0;                              // Whole feet  
  long ins = 0;                             // Whole inches  
  cout << "Enter a length in yards as a decimal: ";  
  cin >> yards;                             // Get the length as yards, feet and inches  
  yds = static_cast<long>(yards);  
  ft = static_cast<long>((yards - yds) * feet_per_yard);  
  ins = static_cast<long>(yards * feet_per_yard * inches_per_foot) % inches_per_foot;  
  cout<<endl<<yards<<" yards converts to "<< yds   <<" yards "<< ft    <<" feet "<<ins<<" inches.";  
  cout << endl;  
  return 0;  
}
```

It works as you expect but I didn't like all the typecasting business. So I changed this to this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long feet_per_yard = 3;
  long inches_per_foot = 12;
  long yards = 0.0;

  long yds = 0;                             // Whole yards
  long ft = 0;                              // Whole feet
  long ins = 0;                             // Whole inches
  cout << "Enter a length in yards as a decimal: ";
  cin >> yards;                             // Get the length as yards, feet and inches
  yds = yards;
  ft = (yards - yds) * feet_per_yard;
  ins = (yards * feet_per_yard * inches_per_foot) % inches_per_foot;

  cout<<endl<<yards<<" yards converts to "<< yds   <<" yards "<< ft    <<" feet "<<ins<<" inches.";
  cout << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Which of course does not work as intended because 'long' doesn't have decimal values like 'double' does, right?

But if I change every value to the type 'double', then % does not work with 'double'. Is there a way to make this easier? I heard about fmod() but CodeBlock IDE doesn't seem to recognize fmod()?

Also, I tried 'float' and it seems that % doesn't work with 'float' either. So what are the types of variables that % work with? And where can I find this reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not recognise `fmod`"?  You'll need to both include the correct header - `#include <math.h>` - and link to the maths library - `-lm`.  If you've done both of these, can you post a copy of the error you get?

Comment: @simonc in C++ `<cmath>` should be used instead

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Also, I tried 'float' and it seems that % doesn't work with 'float' either. So what are the types of variables that % work with? And where can I find this reference?

Comment: @user2826094, of course `%` does not work with `float`s, what would be the sense in that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod), which is inherited from C.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare everything as double and you will then not need to cast.

It makes more sense to use double as number of feet is a continuous quantity.

You can also cast in your expression as in:

```
int daysperweek = 7;
double val = daysperweek * 52.0;  // using 52.0 will use implicit conversion
```